# Android Studio: Cannot Find Symbol Variable navigation_icon_list

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio I get the following error.

error: cannot find symbol variable navigation_icon_list

Here is where its talking about

```
// icon list
TypedArray iconTypedArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.navigation_icon_list);
Integer[] icons = new Integer[iconTypedArray.length()];
for(int i=0; i<iconTypedArray.length(); i++)
{
    icons[i] = iconTypedArray.getResourceId(i, -1);
}
iconTypedArray.recycle();
```

I read on another stackoverflow question that he solved it by removing the `import [appname].R;`. I tried that but it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be the same as what I have been running into quite frequently over the last two months or so. My usual path for resolving the problem is to run `gradle clean` from the command line(doesn't run all the other commands the way an IDE clean does) followed by running the build in the IDE. In some cases this doesn't work and I will do an invalidate and restart in the IDE's file menu.

Also I have noticed that in the android plugin 1.4 betas that I had to run a clean between every build to have changes to XML take effect. (Might be part of why they abandoned the 1.4 plugin and jumped to 1.5?)

Is your import statement red as well as the `R.array.navigation_icon_list`? What version of the IDE, Gradle, and android gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: No the import code is not red. I am using Android Studio 1.4, Gradle 2.2.1 and the Android Plugins is 1.3.0.

Comment: One other thing to verify is that the XML file is included in your srcSets and that your XML is all built correctly. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray The fact that the appname.R class exists and is missing values indicates that your arrays.XML file is not being included in the merge/ process resources tasks.